# Hibernate4 XML named query not known

Tags: java, sql, xml, hibernate

I have this hbm file just to test/practice how to use a named sql in an xml file but it gives me "Named query not known: testQuery1"

```
    public List<Meb_item> namedList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return session.getNamedQuery("testQuery1").list();
}
```

```
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class table="SIDEEFFECT.MEB_ITEM"  name="foreign.Meb_item"> 
  <id name="meddev_item_seq">
   <column name="MEDDEV_ITEM_SEQ"/>
  </id>

  <resultset name="testRs">
    <return   class="foreign.Meb_item">
        <return-property name="item_name" column="item_name"></return-property>
    </return>     
  </resultset>

  <sql-query name="testQuery1" callable="true" >
        select * from meb_item     
    <return   class="foreign.Meb_item" >
        <return-property name="item_name" column="item_name"></return-property>
    </return>    
  </sql-query> 
</class>
```

And here is part of my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
      <mapping resource="mea_class_no.hbm.xml"/>
      <mapping resource="mea_compay.hbm.xml"/>
      <mapping resource="meb_item.hbm.xml"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I've consulted JBoss documents but I could not find what was wrong.
Why does it say the named query is not known ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. 

The sql-query tag seems to be sensitive to the position in the mapping document. 
I moved it from the inside of the class tag to outside of it.
Now it seems to be called as expected. Though it prompts another error.

Here is the whole mapping file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class table="SIDEEFFECT.MEB_ITEM"  name="foreign.Meb_item"> 
<id name="meddev_item_seq">
 <column name="MEDDEV_ITEM_SEQ"/>
</id>
<property name="machinery_area_code">
 <column name="MACHINERY_AREA_CODE"/>
</property>
<property name="cob_flag_code">
 <column name="COB_FLAG_CODE"/>
</property>
<property name="permit_state_code">
 <column name="PERMIT_STATE_CODE"/>
</property>
<property name="meddev_item_no">
 <column name="MEDDEV_ITEM_NO"/>
</property>
<property name="tax_no">
 <column name="TAX_NO"/>
</property>
<property name="item_name">
 <column name="ITEM_NAME"/>
</property>
<property name="permit_date">
 <column name="PERMIT_DATE"/>
</property>
<property name="manuf_country_code">
 <column name="MANUF_COUNTRY_CODE"/>
</property>
<property name="manuf_name">
 <column name="MANUF_NAME"/>
</property>
<property name="manuf_place">
 <column name="MANUF_PLACE"/>
</property>
<property name="manuf_req_country_code">
 <column name="MANUF_REQ_COUNTRY_CODE"/>
</property>
<property name="manuf_req_name">
 <column name="MANUF_REQ_NAME"/>
</property>
<property name="manuf_req_place">
 <column name="MANUF_REQ_PLACE"/>
</property>
<property name="seller_country_code">
 <column name="SELLER_COUNTRY_CODE"/>
</property>
<property name="seller_name">
 <column name="SELLER_NAME"/>
</property>
<property name="seller_place">
 <column name="SELLER_PLACE"/>
</property>
<property name="manuf_import_entp_name">
 <column name="MANUF_IMPORT_ENTP_NAME"/>
</property>
<property name="manuf_import_zip_no">
 <column name="MANUF_IMPORT_ZIP_NO"/>
</property>
<property name="manuf_import_addr1">
 <column name="MANUF_IMPORT_ADDR1"/>
</property>
<property name="manuf_import_addr2">
 <column name="MANUF_IMPORT_ADDR2"/>
</property>
<property name="cancel_withdw_code">
 <column name="CANCEL_WITHDW_CODE"/>
</property>
<property name="cancel_withdw_date">
 <column name="CANCEL_WITHDW_DATE"/>
</property>
<property name="shape">
 <column name="SHAPE"/>
</property>
<property name="sumr_name">
 <column name="SUMR_NAME"/>
</property>
<property name="size_cnt">
 <column name="SIZE_CNT"/>
</property>
<property name="chart_name">
 <column name="CHART_NAME"/>
</property>
<property name="make_method">
 <column name="MAKE_METHOD"/>
</property>
<property name="use_purpose">
 <column name="USE_PURPOSE"/>
</property>
<property name="use_method">
 <column name="USE_METHOD"/>
</property>
<property name="nb">
 <column name="NB"/>
</property>
<property name="valid_term">
 <column name="VALID_TERM"/>
</property>
<property name="exam_std">
 <column name="EXAM_STD"/>
</property>
<property name="permit_cond">
 <column name="PERMIT_COND"/>
</property>
<property name="remark">
 <column name="REMARK"/>
</property>
<property name="meddev_entp_seq">
 <column name="MEDDEV_ENTP_SEQ"/>
</property>
<property name="mea_class_no">
 <column name="MEA_CLASS_NO"/>
</property>
<property name="grade">
 <column name="GRADE"/>
</property>
<property name="receipt_no">
 <column name="RECEIPT_NO"/>
</property>
<property name="bef_doc_id">
 <column name="BEF_DOC_ID"/>
</property>
<property name="safe_exam_yn">
 <column name="SAFE_EXAM_YN"/>
</property>
<property name="export_dev_yn">
 <column name="EXPORT_DEV_YN"/>
</property>
<property name="same_goods_yn">
 <column name="SAME_GOODS_YN"/>
</property>
<property name="same_item_no">
 <column name="SAME_ITEM_NO"/>
</property>
<property name="storage_method">
 <column name="STORAGE_METHOD"/>
</property>
<property name="material">
 <column name="MATERIAL"/>
</property>
<property name="mention_cont">
 <column name="MENTION_CONT"/>
</property>
<property name="regist_ts">
 <column name="REGIST_TS"/>
</property>
<property name="regist_id">
 <column name="REGIST_ID"/>
</property>
<property name="update_ts">
 <column name="UPDATE_TS"/>
</property>
<property name="update_id">
 <column name="UPDATE_ID"/>
</property>
<property name="serv_target">
 <column name="SERV_TARGET"/>
</property>
<property name="trace_manage_target_yn">
 <column name="TRACE_MANAGE_TARGET_YN"/>
</property>
<property name="reexam_yn">
 <column name="REEXAM_YN"/>
</property>
<property name="reexam_valid_start_date">
 <column name="REEXAM_VALID_START_DATE"/>
</property>
<property name="reexam_valid_end_date">
 <column name="REEXAM_VALID_END_DATE"/>
</property>
<property name="serv_target2">
 <column name="SERV_TARGET2"/>
</property>
<property name="bef_cancel_withdw_code">
 <column name="BEF_CANCEL_WITHDW_CODE"/>
</property>
<property name="issue_org_code">
 <column name="ISSUE_ORG_CODE"/>
</property>
<property name="class_change_yn">
 <column name="CLASS_CHANGE_YN"/>
</property>
<property name="delete_yn">
 <column name="DELETE_YN"/>
</property>
<property name="material_ver">
 <column name="MATERIAL_VER"/>
</property>
<property name="disposable_emed_yn">
 <column name="DISPOSABLE_EMED_YN"/>
</property>
</class> 
<sql-query name="testQuery1"  >
        <return   class="foreign.Meb_item" >
            <return-property name="item_name"><return-column name="item_name"/></return-property>
        </return>
        SELECT ITEM_NAME  FROM MEB_ITEM
    </sql-query> 
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

I hope it helps :)